# Is it possible to change the way Terminal displays files' permission?

Tags: terminal

[image: Example image]

As you can see, they are `-rw-r--r--` and so on. I would like to change it to `644` or `755`. How could I do to change it? (Please, this is not a question about `sudo chown`.)

Comment: Please don't add answers directly to the question, post it as an answer instead below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the display of file permission to the octal system, you need to modify the ls command. There is a nice tutorial here: http://agileadam.com/2011/02/755-style-permissions-with-ls/

in short: edit the profile for your shell, f.e.

```
nano ~/.profile
```

and enter

```
alias lso="ls -alG | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(\" %0o \",k);print}'"
```

reload the config file with

```
source ~/.profile
```

and you have the new display type with the command lso

Comment: I found out this answer, to point out the limitation of this way http://askubuntu.com/a/152005/558622

Comment: What is `sud nano` supposed to be?

Comment: sorry, should have typed 'sudo'. Full explanation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo  It shouldn't be necessary because you edit a file in your own user Profile. Well, it was morning and the Coffein hadn't kicked in ;-)

Comment: Not every user is allowed to run `sudo`, so using it to edit your own `.profile` should never be necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that list the file type numeric, the permission bits in octal format, link count, user, group, size in bytes, expanded modification date and file name.

```
stat -f '%2Hp   %Mp%Lp %4l   %10Su   %8Sg %12z  %22Sm   %N' ./*
```

as an alias

```
alias lss="stat -f '%2Hp   %Mp%Lp %4l   %10Su   %8Sg %12z  %22Sm   %N'"

lss /*
 4   0775   41         root      admin         1462    Jun  6 08:29:33 2016   /Applications
 4   0775   14         root      admin          578    Jun 17 12:23:47 2012   /Developer
 4   1775   55         root      admin         1938    May  9 16:52:58 2013   /Library
 4   0755    2         root      wheel           68    Apr  7 21:08:43 2010   /Network
 4   0755    3         root      wheel          136    Dec 19 10:51:54 2011   /System
 4   0755    4         root      admin          170    Sep 22 08:02:08 2013   /Users
 4   1777    2         root      admin          136    Jul 31 06:30:19 2016   /Volumes
 4   0755    2         root      wheel         1394    Oct  2 14:54:37 2014   /bin
 4   1775    2         root      admin           68    Apr  7 21:08:43 2010   /cores
 4   0555    3         root      wheel         4233    Jul 31 06:29:57 2016   /dev
12   0755    1         root      admin           12    Jun 28 09:52:06 2014   /etc
 4   0555    2         root      wheel            1    Jul 31 06:30:18 2016   /home
10   0644    1         root      wheel     20828964    Jun  7 19:35:53 2011   /mach_kernel
 4   0555    2         root      wheel            1    Jul 31 06:30:18 2016   /net
 4   0755    4         root      wheel          136    Aug 19 17:49:09 2013   /opt
 4   0755    6         root      wheel          204    Dec 19 08:59:57 2011   /private
 4   0755    2         root      wheel         2278    Sep 13 15:51:09 2013   /sbin
12   0755    1         root      admin           12    Jun 28 09:51:05 2014   /tmp
 4   0755   13         root      admin          476    Aug  2 11:26:46 2016   /usr
12   0755    1         root      admin           12    Jun 28 09:50:08 2014   /var
```